# When using Ninject in my MVC3 I get a Ninject.ActivationException: Error activating IRepository{Ranking} installed via Nuget

Tags: ninject, ninject.web.mvc

I installed Ninject via nuget, and I registered my binds in NinjectMVC3's RegisterServices method (created by nuget). Follow my code:

```
private static void RegisterServices(IKernel kernel)
{   
    kernel.Bind<IUnitOfWork>().To<UnitOfWork>();
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<Action>>().To<ActionRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<ActionType>>().To<ActionTypeRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<City>>().To<CityRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<Country>>().To<CountryRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<Goods>>().To<GoodsRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<Media>>().To<MediaRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<MediaType>>().To<MediaTypeRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<Ranking>>().To<RankingRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<Role>>().To<RoleRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<Sponsor>>().To<SponsorRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<State>>().To<StateRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<UserAccountInfo>>().To<UserAccountInfoRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<UserAction>>().To<UserActionRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<UserDeservesGoods>>().To<UserDeservesGoodsRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<UserGoods>>().To<UserGoodsRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IRepository<User>>().To<UserRepository>();
    kernel.Bind<IUserService>().To<UserService>();
    kernel.Bind<IAccountService>().To<AccountService>();

    DependencyResolver.SetResolver(new NinjectDependencyResolver(kernel));
}
```

here is my HomeController:

```
readonly IRepository<Ranking> repoRanking;
public HomeController(IRepository<Ranking> repoRanking)
{
    this.repoRanking = repoRanking;
}
```

When I execute HomeController, I get follow exception:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: Ninject.ActivationException: Error activating IRepository{Ranking}
No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.
Activation path:
 2) Injection of dependency IRepository{Ranking} into parameter repoRanking of constructor of type HomeController
 1) Request for HomeController

Suggestions:
 1) Ensure that you have defined a binding for IRepository{Ranking}.
 2) If the binding was defined in a module, ensure that the module has been loaded into the kernel.
 3) Ensure you have not accidentally created more than one kernel.
 4) If you are using constructor arguments, ensure that the parameter name matches the constructors parameter name.
 5) If you are using automatic module loading, ensure the search path and filters are correct.
```

What I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you created a default module where you set your bindings instead of in the register services method?

```
 public class DefaultModule : NinjectModule {
    public override void Load() {
        Bind<IProductService>().To<ProductService>().InTransientScope();
    }
 }
```

and then in your Global.asax file do this:

```
 protected override IKernel CreateKernel() {
  var kernel = new StandardKernel();

  kernel.Load(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());

 return kernel;
 }
```

Comment: Hi @Josh, the RegisterServices method already set my bindings. Anyway, I tested your suggestion and did not works.

Comment: Hi,  I Solved my problem, I set my DependencyResolver two times. I removed in Global.asax and my code worked properly. Thanks